# How to display result a mysql query in node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to display the result of my query using res.end but i can't since i'm new to Node.js,Here's part of my code where the user enters the username and password in a form in an html file and i want to display the result of a query which is the username but what i'm getting is the all rows in the database table :

```
     app.post('/login/:email', function (req, res){
      connection.connect();
      email = req.body.email;
      password = req.body.password;
     if(email && password )
     {
     console.log(email);
     console.log(password);
   connection.query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE email = email and password = password', function     (error, rows, fields) { 

        str='';
        for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
        str = str + rows[i].username +'\n';
         res.end( str);


      }); 
      connection.end(); 
     } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting whole table because of this:

```
   connection.query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE email = email and password = password', function     (error, rows, fields) {
```

Every row has `email = email and password = password`, that is because both left and right side are evaluated as column name. That is like saying `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 1 = 1`.

Try  changing it to:

```
   connection.query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE email = ? and password = ?', [email, password], function     (error, rows, fields) {
```

Comment: P.S. I just modified the answer, the previous format `:email` requires also changing some configuration. the format `?` is easier to use  in your case.

Answer (score 0):

connection.query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE email = "email" and password = "password"', function     (error, rows, fields)

//hope this will work i add " " because string contain "" in query